# mysql_num_rows() Error

Tags: php, mysql, post, rows

```
<html>
<form action="update.php" method="POST" name="ID">
<input type="text" name="ID"">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Up there is the submit form to get an ID number.
I try to get that ID entered by user ( NOTE: It's a number) and show mysql table row coresponding to that ID.
Example : User enter 2 and row number 2 from database is shown.
My problem is that all rows are shown and not only wanted one.
- Extra Question : How can I show user an error if he entered a NULL value ?

```
<?php
    $id=$_POST['ID'];
    .
    .
    .
    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

    if (!mysql_select_db($database))
        die("Can't select database");
    $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID= '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vbots");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $query);

    mysql_close();
    .
    .
    .
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running your query.

You have this:

```
$query="SELECT FROM table WHERE ID= '$id'";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vbots");
```

You want this:

```
$query="SELECT FROM table WHERE ID= '$id'";
$result = mysql_query( $query);
```

*****Insert nag about SQL injection*****

Comment: Ok thank you , i fixed that .
Could you tell me how to check if user didn't enter a value and just pressed POST or used a-z characters?

Answer (score 0):

It should be this.

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['ID'];

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID= '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $query);

mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to check if $id is null:
   if (!isset($id))
        die("Enter a value for id!");